# Do national labs in the US accept international post docs who come with funding from their own government?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, international-students

I am from Finland, which provides funding for postdoc research abroad.

I want to use that funding to do postdoc research in a national lab in the US.

Will national laboratories in the US accept post docs who come with their own funding from the country they are from?

Comment: surely you are in a better position to answer than anyone else...

Comment: Do you or your PhD advisor have any connections to appropriate US national labs? Do you have any idea which lab(s) would be suitable? Does the funding source have any good connections, including previous personnel who have successfully taken advantage of their funding?

Comment: My Ph.D. supervisor doesn’t have any connections from USA national labs. The funding agency does only need an invitation letter from the host.

Comment: I don't understand from this post what the issue is and what you know and do not know. What is the step you need help with?

Comment: I suggest first trying to find scientists you're interested in working with, and then finding out what could be done. At least DOE labs may have concerns about such foreign funding, but there is sometimes more flexibility if you're officially associated with a local university despite in practice working at the lab.

Comment: @Anyon - Office of Science labs should not have issues with an externally-paid visitor. NNSA labs are a different question.

Comment: Your question remains unclear. *"I have funding from my home country to do postdoc research in USA National Labs"* - okay, great, you have funding for a post doc at a US national lab. *"any suggestions on how it will work?"* - What do you mean, "how it will work"? *"I am trying to find someone who works in USA national labs as my supervisor." * - Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: *"I want to know does it really works for one who has a home country-sponsored researcher who wants to work in USA National Laboratories as a post-doc??"* Do you mean to ask whether it's possible for someone with foreign funding to work at a US national lab? This seems in conflict with your first sentence. Do you mean you're not sure how to find a supervisor? Do you mean you're not sure if your post doc funding can be used at a national lab in the US vs. at a university? Are you wondering about restrictions by the Finland government or the US government?

Comment: I mean Finland provides funding for postdoc research abroad. I want to use that funding to do postdoc research in USA national labs. My question is whether USA national labs will accept me or not to do a postdoc???

Comment: What is the area of research? Some US National Labs are heavily involved in research for the US Department of Defense (DoD) and might not be able to accommodate a non-citizen postdoc at all.  Others have areas devoted to DoD work and other areas to nonDoD work and it might be possible to find a place there.

Comment: Its chemical engineering related to bioaviation fuel and catalysis. I am looking to find someone at PNNL. my area of interest is open for all as per my understanding from there website

Comment: @DilipSarwate - both Los Alamos and Lawrence Livermore have non-US-citizen postdocs and staff. Hard to come up with labs with more sensitive DOE (note, not DOD) work. But they are big and do work in many different areas, some open, some not so open.

Answer (score 2):

That depends strongly on the field. In nuclear anything, no it is incredibly unlikely to happen. In most biology fields, it is quite likely to happen as you already have funding and are merely looking for lab space (presumably). In Chemistry, it again depends on the area of study. This is a very vague and encompassing answer because there is little detail (understandably) in your question, so do not take it to heart and certainly try even if it is in nuclear research.

Assuming you have already gotten the funding opportunity from Finland, the area of research is nailed down. And likely the specific question is already waiting for lab space (or equivalent) to be answered using the Finland funds. If this is the case, you also likely have an idea about which national lab would be best equipped to help you with this hypothesis.

Assuming all of these things are true, check the websites of the top 5 most likely labs to host you. Somewhere on there will be contact information for whom to contact/ask that will be better equipped to answer your exact situation.